# How can you accept optional parameters in a RegEx expression?

Tags: regex, optimization, option-type

I want to simplify this expression a bit. Is there a better way to do this using lookups, or something? I'm pretty junior when it comes to regex. The params $3, $5 and $7 params are optional. $1 is required.

```
^
/application/
([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)
([\/]([0-9a-zA-Z_]+))?
([/\?|\?|\/]([^\?]*))?
([\?](.*))?
$

service => $1
target  => $3
args    => $5
filter  => $7
```

/application/blender/banana?add=milk.

btw Im using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to build and test expressions, its a great tool if you havent heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
([\/]([0-9a-zA-Z_]+))?
```

can be simplified to:

```
(\/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)?
```

and:

```
([\?](.*))?
```

can be simplified to:

```
(\?.*)?
```

because the `+` and `*` (and also `?`) apply to only the preceding item.

I'm not sure what this:

```
[/\?|\?|\/]
```

is supposed to be. Perhaps you mean:

```
(?:/\?|\?|\/)
```

i.e. either `/?` or `?` or `/`. (The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.)

This gives:

```
^
/application/
([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)
(\/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+)?
((?:/\?|\?|\/)[^?]*)?
(\?.*)?
$

service => $1
target  => $2
args    => $3
filter  => $4
```

Comment: woot! thats awesome =], yeah I meant the non-capt. The issue sometimes third parties append their own ? to our query string so I need a way to detect that last filter and treat it as a set of args. Also I dont want any of the slashes in the output values, your $2 does that, yeah?

Comment: Yes. If you don't want the slash in the second capture group you can do this: `(?:\/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+))?`. Alternatively, you can just strip out the slashes from the captured text after the event.